# Private static property in c#

Tags: c#, properties, static

Do I need to mark public method as static if I want to initialize private variable only once or it is enough for making "singleton property" in the following code?

```
public IEqualityComparer<T> GetComparer<T>()
{
    if (typeof (IUserShift).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (T)))
        return UserShiftComparer.Value as IEqualityComparer<T>;

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("There is no avaliable comparer for the type!", nameof(T));
}

private static readonly Lazy<UserShiftTrackingComparer> UserShiftComparer = new Lazy<UserShiftTrackingComparer>();
```

Comment: No.  The static variable is initialized at most once, in the [type initializer](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) for the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your field `static` then only one copy will exist and in this case since you have it within `Lazy`, it will only be created when it is accessed. If it is never accessed, it will never be created.

Making your method `static` means it is not tied to an instance of the class but the class itself. All instance methods can access static methods and static fields and instance fields and instance methods. On the other hand, static methods can only access static fields and other static methods.

To answer your question, you **DO NOT** need to make the method static to initialize the `UserShiftComparer` only once.